# Connecting HDMI-only monitor to GPU or motherboard

Tags: motherboard, hdmi, gpu, displayport

I have a Gigabyte GeForce GTX 970. My GPU has 3 Display Ports and 1 HDMI. I have two monitors, which only support HDMI. So I wanted to know, should I connect one monitor to my GPU and the other to my motherboard, or instead buy an adapter so both monitors can be connected to the GPU?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The GTX 970 is [superior](http://gpu.userbenchmark.com/Compare/Nvidia-GTX-970-vs-Intel-HD-4600-Desktop-125-GHz/2577vs2168) in all respects to motherboard/CPU graphics (for rough comparison the link compares Intel HD 4600 with the GTX 970). So I recommend that you connect *both* monitors to the GTX 970.

Buy the adapter, something like this: https://www.startech.com/AV/Displayport-Converters/DisplayPort-to-HDMI-Adapter-Converter-Cable~DP2HDMI.

Have fun!